# Matrix Equation Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Does anybody know how to solve this matrix equation

\begin{equation}
{
I = S - RSQ,
}
\end{equation}

where 
$I$ is the identity matrix, 
$R$, $Q$ are known matrices, and 
$S$ is the unknown matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as $$I=ISI-RSQ$$ and apply vectorization
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm vec}(I) = (I\otimes I-Q^T\otimes R)\,{\rm vec}(S) \cr
 {\rm vec}(S) = (I\otimes I-Q^T\otimes R)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(I) \cr
 S = {\rm devec}\Big((I\otimes I-Q^T\otimes R)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(I)\Big) \cr
}$$
If you can transform the equation into a Sylvester equation, then you can use a more efficient solver like Bartels–Stewart instead of this brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following series converge, then
$$S=I+RQ+R^2Q^2+\cdots$$

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find the sum of the series and obtained the equation.